# Telegram login widget. Why is the callback not being called?

Tags: go, telegram, telegram-bot

My sequence of actions:

1. Creating a bot.
2. Launch the bot on the backend with one endpoint (`/telegram-callback`).
3. I assign the domain to the bot from @BotFather: `https://www.example.ru/telegram-callback`.
   At this moment Telegram calls `/telegram-callback`. I understand that it just checks if the endpoint is alive. Here is the log from nginx:
   `149.154.161.244 - - - - [18/Oct/2023:07:50:49 +0300] "GET /telegram-callback HTTP/1.1" 200 0 0 "-" "TelegramBot (like TwitterBot)"`
4. Making a widget on https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login.
   Authorization Type: Callback
   Request Access: true
5. Click 'Login in with Telegram'
6. Enter my phone number and press NEXT
7. I get a system notification from Telegram to confirm the session, so I click Confirm.

After that someone should call GET `/telegram-callback` with user parameters? The nginx logs are empty, the bot logs are empty too. Bot code:

```
import (
    tgbotapi "github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5"
    "go.uber.org/zap"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func handleTelegramOAuthCallback(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    zap.L().Debug("handleTelegramOAuthCallback", zap.String("url", r.URL.String()),
        zap.String("encode", r.URL.Query().Encode()))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/telegram-callback", handleTelegramOAuthCallback)

    go func() {
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
    }()

    bot, err := tgbotapi.NewBotAPI("TOKEN")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    bot.Debug = true
    updateConfig := tgbotapi.NewUpdate(0)
    updateConfig.Timeout = 10
    updates := bot.GetUpdatesChan(updateConfig)
    for update := range updates {
        if update.Message == nil {
            continue
        }
        msg := tgbotapi.NewMessage(update.Message.Chat.ID, update.Message.Text)
        msg.ReplyToMessageID = update.Message.MessageID
        if _, err = bot.Send(msg); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```